# Proper definition of set between two functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a parameter $\delta \in (0,1)$.
The parameter is further restricted from below and above by the functions $\underline \delta : (0,\ln(4)] \to (0,1)$ and $\overline \delta : (0,\ln(4)] \to (0,1)$ respectively where
\begin{align}
&\underline \delta(r) = \sup\left\{0,1 - \frac{\ln(2)}{r}\right\},\\[2mm]
&\overline \delta(r) = 1 + \frac{\ln(3) - \ln(2+e^r)}{r}.
\end{align}
I want to define the set $A$ that captures all point $(r,\delta)$ such that $r \in (0,\ln(4)]$ and $\delta \in [\underline \delta(r), \overline \delta(r)]$. Is the following definition correct? 
\begin{align}
(r,\delta) \in (0,\ln(4)] \times \left\{\delta \in [\underline \delta(r), \overline \delta(r)] \mid r \in (0,\ln(4)] \right\} =: A.
\end{align} 
I'm a bit confused, because $r$ and $\delta$ turn up at the left and right hand side of $\in$

Comment: Your definition is confusingly incorrect, because the set after the $\times$ depends on $r.$ Instead, you can define $A$ as in William Elliot's answer, or else as $$A=\bigcup_{r\in(0,\ln 4]}(\{r\}\times[\delta(r),\overline\delta(r)])$$

Comment: By the way, since the set after $\sup$ has only two elements, wouldn't it be more natural to write $\max$ instead of $\sup$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A = { $(r,\delta) : r \in (0,\ln(4)], \delta \in [\underline \delta(r), \overline \delta(r)]$ }.